# Need help for Grub configuration

Tags: boot, opensuse, grub

I have a problem with my boot configuration of grub. I installed openSuse on my Laptop and now my Windows 8 disappeared from the boot menu.

I am not sure if I use EFI, but I can see it the fdisk list.

```
linux-k7x3:~ # fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 904D3D2C-D620-48FD-A125-99EAE86BD714

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    616447    614400   300M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     616448    821247    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3     821248   1083391    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1083392 767606783 766523392 365.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  767606784 771827711   4220928     2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  771827712 854079487  82251776  39.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  854079488 976773119 122693632  58.5G Microsoft basic data
```

I am wondering, that fdisk doesn't identify the types correctly. sda4 is my Windows partion and sda5 swap, sda5 and sda6 are ext4 for openSuse.

I tried to find the configuration:

```
linux-k7x3:/boot/efi/EFI/opensuse # cat grub.cfg 
set btrfs_relative_path="yes"
search --fs-uuid --set=root 21e3befa-5399-4e75-a853-d2fd67b595cb
set prefix=(${root})/boot/grub2
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Where can I check and change my boot configuration?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `grub2-mkconfig` will probe for operating systems and add them to the grub menu.

https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled-12/book_sle_admin/data/sec_grub2_commands.html#vle_grub2_mkconfig

It also says that grub's config is here

> /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

FYI, Ubuntu and Debian based distros use `update-grub` to do the same thing.